# Foreach - add notation to foreach loop, do i need a nested foreach

Tags: git, powershell, foreach

I need some help with my script; I have done the first part but the second part I'm not entirely sure whether a second foreach is needed. 
Firstly the script outputs files and hash's from a branch. Next to the hash I have managed to add a notation which i can change later to output "hash" the second part I want to put "file" next to each file outputted, below I have included how the output should be and it is like that; but I just can't seem to get "file" notation next to each filename.

```
$GitList = git log master..branch2 --pretty=format:'%H' --reverse


foreach ($hash in $GitList) {
    "$hash hash"
    $files = git show $hash --pretty="format:" --name-only
    $files
}


#-------------------------------output should be like below

37b970b35681728db2faa4135681728d hash
branch2/ScriptPart1.ps1 file
37b970b371a7805a657030f687135681728d hash
branch2/ScriptPart2.ps1 file
branch2/ScriptPart3.ps1 file
37b970b30a137b970b381e5d5135681728d hash
branch2/ScriptPart2.ps1 file
321b2feb5d37b970b32d47f4135681728d hash
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but yes, you're going to have to loop over the list of `$files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a quick and dirty foreach-object and be done with it...  Something along the lines of:

```
$files | Foreach-Object { "{0} file" -f $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem might be, that the return value of the line:

```
git show $hash --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

is handled by PowerShell as a string array with two items of which the first one contains an empty string.

Adressing the second item directly would be a way to achieve what you want to do here:

```
$GitList = git log master --pretty=format:'%H' --reverse

foreach ($hash in $GitList) {
    "$hash hash"
    (git show $hash --pretty="format:" --name-only)[1] + ' file'
}
```

By the way: Depending on your scenario you may consider using PSObjects as output. Especially if you plan to further process the output of your script by PowerShell:

```
foreach ($hash in $GitList) {
    $file = (git show $hash --pretty="format:" --name-only)[1]
    New-Object -Type psobject -Property @{'Hash'= $hash; 'File' = $file}
}
```